# Trying to select a specific number inside of a Selenium WebElement

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

In the webpage, I am trying to select the 24 off of a page number which is on there as `<li class="pager__item pager__item--current">24</li>`

I have a WebElement that I am selecting with `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".pager__item--current"));`  Is it possible to grab the 24 off of it using this?  When I convert it to a string and print it out, I just get the .cssSelector statement in selenium.

I'm converting it to a string using:

```
    WebElement k = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".pager__item--current"));
    String element = k.toString();
    System.out.println("" + element);
```

I get `[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (a2356021-3e80-4091-9b9d-51b9b08ec8b7)] -> css selector: .pager__item--current]` from this.

How can I extract the 24 from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getText()` method:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".pager__item--current")).getText();
```

More details here:
https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText()

Comment: Thanks, knew I was missing something simple